# How click Next Button and Back Button in array index

Tags: android

I'm creating an app on android for viewing the image when I select the next button to show the new image and the back button to show previous image but when the press the next button to the maximum index , i want it to show the start from first image index and when the press the back button to the minimum index, i want it to show the start from maxminum image index. I have problem when i click the back button go to 0 index i want it show the image from the final index and also when i click the next button go to final index i want it show the from the 0 index. *

```
    if (v == btn_back) {
        if((currentimageindex)!=0){
            imageview.setImageResource(IMAGE_IDS[currentimageindex]);
               mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, myMusic[currentsoundindex]);
               mp.start();
              --currentimageindex;
              --currentsoundindex;
           }
          if((currentimageindex)==0){
                    imageview.setImageResource(IMAGE_IDS[currentimageindex]);
                       mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, myMusic[currentsoundindex]);
                       mp.start();
              --currentimageindex;
              --currentsoundindex;}
    if(v== btn next){*******}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `--currentimageindex` with:

```
currentimageindex = (currentimageindex + IMAGE_IDS.length -1) % IMAGE_IDS.length;
```

When the index is 0 this will make it will wrap around to `IMAGE_IDS.length-1`.

Note, for going forward you only need do this:

```
currentimageindex = (currentimageindex + 1) % IMAGE_IDS.length;
```